# Page X of Y issue

Tags: itext

I tried 3 different ways of displaying Page numbers,  `OnCloseDocument` content is not displaying in the page, none of them worked.

My Intention is displaying **Page numbers** like this

**1 of 10

  2 0f 10

..............

............

 10 of 10 
 on each page**

I know how to display

**1 

2 

3

4

....

10**

but **don`t know how to display total page number**

I`m using   **OnCloseDocument**  to display  No.of pages count,but the **content in it is
not displaying.**

```
public class MyPdfPageEventHelpPageNo : iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper
{
    protected PdfTemplate total;
    protected BaseFont helv;
    private bool settingFont = false;

    public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        template= writer.DirectContent.CreateTemplate(100, 100);       

        bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    }
    public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
    //See below
    }
```

**1ST WAY:**

```
    public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)     
    {
        //I create a table with one column like below.
        PdfPTable pageNumber2 = new PdfPTable(1);
        pageNumber2.TotalWidth = 50;
        pageNumber2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

        pageNumber2.AddCell(BuildTable2RightCells("Page " + writer.PageNumber));
        pageNumber.AddCell(BuildTable2LeftCells(writer.PageCount));
        pageNumber2.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 500, 
        (document.PageSize.GetBottom(140)), cb);
    }
```

**2ND WAY:**

```
    public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)     
    {
        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(template,Element.ALIGN_CENTER,new
        Phrase(writer.PageNumber.ToString()), 500, 140, 0);
    }
```

**3RD WAY:**

```
    public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)     
    {
        template.BeginText();
        template.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
        template.SetTextMatrix(500, 140);
        template.ShowText(Convert.ToString((writer.PageNumber - 1)));
        template.EndText();
    }
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your second way is probably the simplest way. Below is a very, very slimmed down but working version:

```
public class MyPdfPageEventHelpPageNo : iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper {
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(writer.DirectContent, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(writer.PageNumber.ToString()), 500, 140, 0);
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
//Create a file on our desktop
string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "OnCloseTest.pdf");
//Standard PDF creation, adjust as needed
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER)) {
        using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {

            //Find our custom event handler
            writer.PageEvent = new MyPdfPageEventHelpPageNo();

            doc.Open();

            //Add text the first page
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Test"));

            //Add a new page with more text
            doc.NewPage();
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Another Test"));

            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

*Sorry, I thought that you were having problems with the basic setup of events, my mistake.*

I've only seen two ways to do what you are trying to do, either do two passes or use the [PdfTemplate syntax which renders an image as far as I know](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104).

I'd recommend just running two passes, the first just to create your PDF and the second to add your page numbers. You can run your first pass to a `MemoryStream` so you don't have to hit the disk twice if you want.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(outputFile);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(secondFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs)) {
        int PageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
        for (int i = 1; i <= PageCount; i++) {
            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.Format("Page {0} of {1}", i, PageCount)), 500, 140, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, though I wish I could figure out why the templating method doesn't work as I can see that as being more powerful.

Comment: Why the secondFile and how do you create it?

Comment: That works well. My only problem is that I have some pages in my document which are portrait and some which are landscape. Is there an easy way I can tell which is which and adjust the x coordinate for the 'page x of y' accordingly?

Comment: @RachelEdge, the `PdfReader` object has a method called [`GetPageSizeWithRotation()`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfReader.cs#l446) that should do what you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

Here is sample code for for the "Chris Haas" explanation (the two pass method with out writing file into harddisk)

The "copy and paste code" using memorystream for page x of y output

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] b = CreatePDF2();        
    string ss = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
    string filenamefirst = ss + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyHHmmss");
    string filenamefirstpdf = filenamefirst + ".pdf";

    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(b))
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filenamefirstpdf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
            {
                int PageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
                BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

                for (int i = 1; i <= PageCount; i++)
                {
                   string sss = String.Format("Page {0} of {1}", i, PageCount);
                   PdfContentByte over=  stamper.GetOverContent(i);
                   over.BeginText();                        
                   over.SetTextMatrix(500, 750);
                   over.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);                                              
                   over.ShowText(sss);
                   over.EndText();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private byte[] CreatePDF2()
{
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 50, 50, 50, 50);

    using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, output);
        doc.Open();

        Paragraph header = new Paragraph("My Document") { Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER };
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Testing the iText pdf.");
        Phrase phrase = new Phrase("This is a phrase but testing some formatting also. \nNew line here.");
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk("This is a chunk.");

        PdfPTable tab = new PdfPTable(3);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 24F)));
        cell.Colspan = 3;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right   //Style
        cell.BorderColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
        cell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER; // | Rectangle.TOP_BORDER;
        cell.BorderWidthBottom = 3f;
        tab.AddCell(cell);
        //row 1

        for (int i = 1; i < 120; i++)
        {
            //row 1
            tab.AddCell("R1C1");
            tab.AddCell("R1C2");
            tab.AddCell("R1C3");
            //row 2
            tab.AddCell("R2C1");
            tab.AddCell("R2C2");
            tab.AddCell("R2C3");
        }

        doc.Add(header);
        doc.Add(paragraph);
        doc.Add(phrase);
        doc.Add(chunk);
        doc.Add(tab);
        doc.Close();
        return output.ToArray();
    }
}
```